# invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'int[]' When accessing integer array pointed by a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to learn pointer in C and am writing this little integer array pointer exercise,but ran into a invalid application of `sizeof` to incomplete type `int[]` problem. Please tell me where did I go wrong and how to solve it. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int intA[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int intB[];

void int_copy(const int *source, int *destionation, int nbr)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<nbr;i++)
    {
        *destionation++ = *source++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int *ptrA = intA;
    int *ptrB = intB;

    int sizeA = sizeof(intA);
    int nbrA = sizeof(intA)/sizeof(int);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("[Debug]The size of intA is:%d\n", sizeA);
    printf("[Debug]That means the number of elements is:%d\n", nbrA);

    printf("\n\nThe values of intA are:\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<nbrA;i++)
    {
        printf("[%d]->%d\n", i, intA[i]);
    }


    int_copy(ptrA, ptrB, nbrA);
    int sizeB = sizeof(intB);
    int nbrB = sizeof(intB)/sizeof(int);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("[Debug]The size of intB is:%d\n", sizeB);
    printf("[Debug]That means the number of elements is:%d\n", nbrB);

    printf("\n\nThe values of intB are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<nbrB;i++)
    {
         printf("[%d]->%d\n", i, *ptrB++);
    }

}

# cc -g -o int_copy int_copy.c
int_copy.c: In function 'main':
int_copy.c:36: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'int[]' 
int_copy.c:37: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'int[]'
```

The strange thing that I observed is when I ran gdb, I monitored that the copy function, int_copy, runs for 9 times which seems to be right, but the print of intB after the copy function only displays one item in that array.

I'm still struggling about pointers now, so please do help me and forgive my ignorance. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

`intB` is basically a pointer, and `sizeof` on it will yield the same as `sizeof` on `int`, that's why the print appears only once.
`intA` is an array with a known size, so the `sizeof` works.

You need to remember that `sizeof` is not a run-time call, although it may look so syntactically. It's a built-in operator that returns the size of the type in bytes at the compilation time, and at the compilation time `intB` is a pointer that should later point to a newly allocated array.

Comment: Thank you littleadv. That's really a good answer, I changed the declaration of intB with a fixed length, then everything is okay now.int intA[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int intB[9];

Comment: So basically that means the sizeof is not a runtime call, right? I got another answer from my friend, he said the length of array cannot be dynamically changed, is this right?

Comment: @bestwc - length of the array cannot be changed, if you don't know the length upfront, you should either declare some maximum length and waste space, or use dynamic allocations (and then you can reallocate).

Comment: @bestwc: `sizeof` is computed at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You are also in trouble here, because IntB doesn't have a size so int_copy really doesn't work for it. There is nowhere to copy the ints!

When declaring an array, you have to either give the size inside [] or use an initializer with the values, so the compiler can count them and figure out the size itself.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your `int intB[];` statement is invalid, which compiler are you using?

Also, beware that arrays and pointers are not really the same.  You can however use the array handle in a call to a function that expects a pointer, so you can give `intA` to your `int_copy` function without copying it to a pointer.  http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I know why int intB[]; is invalid? I'm using gcc version 4.2.1 20070719  [FreeBSD]. And as for this exercise I am trying to practice the usage of pointer and array, so I really didn't think about having a pointer pointed to an array is extra.

Comment: If you compile with the option `-pedantic`, it tells you why.